How to implement a simple wrapper app to change settings like precise google location for the duration of runtime of a specific app?
I don't want to enable 'precise google location'¹ on my phone.
I would like to know if someone know a way to make a wrapper (can be a shell script triggered by an app, or a simple new app) to do this processing:

click on a icon of the wrapper
enable precision¹
run the app with the geo setting
when the app is no more active, remove permission

Is this easily feasible? Any smart advice? What are guidelines?

I am not sure I fully understand your question but from what I gather you can try. PMX developed by our site regular // Enable permission watcher from settings and disable location permissions (both coarse and fine) //Use the app and when it prompts you to give location permission, do that and once you exit the app, you will find a notification asking you if the permission needs to be revoked or kept//choose revoke

Perhaps [tag:automation] is what you're looking for. Some of them allow wrapping automation as a home screen widget // cc: @beeshyams
